# Side-by-side diff (-y) : how to hide the reverse-video ^M (at end-of-line)?

Tags: linux, text, diff, gnu, eol

### Problem

I'm diffing files side-by-side (`-y`) on a GNU/Linux system:

```
$ diff -y file1 file2
```

but each end-of-line results in **spurious `^M` in reverse video**... one for the left line and one for the right line.

Here's the version of `diff` I'm using:

```
diff (GNU diffutils) 3.3
```

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention I'm combining `diff` with `less`, and without `| less` the `^M` are not shown:

```
$ diff -y file1 file2 | less
```

### Question

How can one avoid these reverse-video ^M chars to be produced by `diff`?

---

**Note1:** Without the `-y` I don't have the problem. But I need this argument.

**Note2:** I can't do unix2dos or dos2unix on any of the files because I must use them read-only.

**Note3:** I have found similar questions that correspond to using `diff` with GIT, they didn't seem to be helpful in my case - I'm not using GIT here, just `diff`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `diff -y --strip-trailing-cr file1 file2`.

Comment: And for the complete answer, the command becomes: `diff --strip-trailing-cr -y file1 file2 | less`